# ShellExecuteEx guid path

Tags: c++, winapi, guid

I have a path of the form

```
::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\Fonts
```

If I enter this into the explorer address bar it correctly opens Control Panel - Fonts.

How can I execute the same using ShellExecuteEx or something similar (a path containing guids)?

Comment: Don't use Guid paths like this. You should instead use `SHGetFolderPath(CSID_FONTS)` or `SHGetKnownFolderID(FOLDERID_Fonts)` to get the path to the Fonts folder, and then you can open that path with `ShellExecute/Ex()`.

Comment: *"How can I execute the same using ShellExecuteEx"* - What do you mean? You cannot execute a directory.

Comment: @remy this isn't in the file system though

Comment: opening `::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\Fonts` and opening `C:\Windows\Fonts` directly show the same display - a list of installed fonts.

Comment: @Remy Perhaps in this case, for that path, on some machines, but I'm sure you know that not all objects in the shell namespace are file system objects.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that

Comment: I am given a guid path from a shellobject parsingname and have zero control over the format. The provided solution of using shell:: is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open such GUID pathes you have to prepend the `shell:` protocol to the path:

```
shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\Fonts
```

Note that GUID pathes often **change between Windows versions**, for instance the above path doesn't work on my Windows 10 machine.

A better approach is to use the **[known folder API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911(v=vs.85).aspx)** to get a PIDL that points to the folder and open that PIDL using `ShellExecuteEx`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <atlbase.h>  // CComHeapPtr

struct CComInit
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    CComInit() { hr = ::CoInitialize(nullptr); }
    ~CComInit() { if( SUCCEEDED(hr) ) ::CoUninitialize(); }
};

int main() 
{
    CComInit com;
    if( FAILED( com.hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize COM, error: 0x" << std::hex << com.hr << '\n';
        return static_cast<int>( com.hr );
    }

    CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidl;
    HRESULT hr = ::SHGetKnownFolderIDList( FOLDERID_Fonts, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, nullptr, &pidl );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "SHGetKnownFolderIDList failed with error 0x" << std::hex << hr << '\n';
        return static_cast<int>( hr );
    }

    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW si{ sizeof(si) };
    si.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOASYNC | SEE_MASK_IDLIST;
    si.nShow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
    si.lpVerb = L"open";
    si.lpIDList = pidl;

    if( !::ShellExecuteExW( &si ) )
    {
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        std::cout << "ShellExecuteExW failed with error " << err << '\n';
        return static_cast<int>( err );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

- The ATL class `CComHeapPtr` is a smart pointer that automatically calls `CoTaskMemFree()` in its destructor to correctly deallocate the PIDL that was allocated by the shell. If you don't want to use it, you have to call `CoTaskMemFree()` manually or use your own RAII wrapper to do this.
- The flag `SEE_MASK_NOASYNC` is used because the example is a console program that will exit immediately after the `ShellExecuteEx` call.

Comment: the guid path is what is returned from the ShellObject ParsingName - so at the very least I'd have to parse it before executing - using shell:: is perfect.

Comment: @mtissington You might accept this answer then. You might also like to review other questions to see if there are good answers to be accepted.